# Filter Sales/order collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, zend-framework

I am trying to get data where if my `order state` is `complete` and `delivery_at` is between `date1 and date 2`.

At the same time I also want to filter when state = `canceled` and delivery_at is between `date3 and date4`.

Point is that there are two conditions to filer : when (state = A and delivery_at = X) OR (state = 'canceled' and delivery_at = Y)

The code which I wrote is :

```
orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                   new \Zend_Db_Expr("(state = 'complete') OR (state = 'canceled')")
```

In the above code, I haven't done filtering on delivery_at, as the above query is failing even then, as the count I get is 0;

So, how can I do in this current situation.

EDIT :: **MY EXACT QUERY**

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
    $orderCollection->getSelect()->where(
                    new Zend_Db_Expr("(state = 'complete' AND DATE(delivery_at) >= '{$from}' AND DATE(delivery_at) <= '{$to}') OR (state = 'canceled' AND DATE(delivery_at) >= '{$from}' AND DATE(delivery_at) <= '{$to}'))")
                );
```

Error message :

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` WHERE ((state = 'complete' AND DATE(delivery_at) >= '2020-02-25' AND DATE(delivery_at) = '2020-02-25' AND DATE(delivery_at) ";i:1;s:2171:"#0 /var/www/html/fresh/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly query

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("(state = 'complete') OR (state = 'canceled')")
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is happening is if I put the OR, and after that anything in bracket it throws an error. I have updated the answer with my exact query and the error log.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Missed a bracket.